# HIChart not showing graph when first time loads android

Tags: java, android, highcharts, rendering

I am using HiChart android library, I have done all setup but does not show graph when it loads first time. If i pause the activity and start it again then graph shows.

Answer (score 0):

```
chartview.setFocusable(true);
```

This line will help you.

Comment: Hi Vinayak, where should I put this ?
I am facing same issue like you .